# How to link report parameter with query parameter in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a query in SSRS (against oracle)

```
select * from myTable
where t.user = :myUser
```

However, when I go to preview tab, it does not give me an option to input the myUser value.

I thought the whole point of adding a parameter is so that user can interactively enter values?

What exact steps am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the DataSet definition page, there should be a tab called Parameters. You should be able to list the Query Parameters there, and hook them up to Report Parameters. With SQL Server queries it does this for you, but you may need to do it yourself for Oracle.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Parameters are actually defined in the Report -> Report Parameters menu

Comment: yeah, I missed that the first time I read it, edited that part out